# mysqli_result::free not working, still getting "Commands out of sync" error

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a problem with `mysqli_result::free`. I thought I understand how it works, but I'm still getting errors.
Here's the code. I know it's not perfect, but  please, comment any other flaws in it after answering main question:

```
$config = parse_ini_file('../config.ini', true);
$mysqli = new mysqli($config['database']['host'], $config['database']['user'], $config['database']['password'], $config['database']['database']);

if($mysqli->connect_errno > 0) {
    die('Unable to connect to database ['. $mysqli->connect_error .']');
}

$sql = 'CALL Stored_Procedure()';

if(!$result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    die('There was an error running the query ['. $mysqli->error .']');
} else {
    $array = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}

foreach($array as $row) {
    //Do something with each row of the result array
}

$result->free();

$sql = 'CALL Other_Stored_Procedure()';

if(!$result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    die('There was an error running the query ['. $mysqli->error .']');
} else {
    $array = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}

foreach($array as $row) {
    //Do something with each row of the result array
}

$result->free();
$mysqli->close();
```

I'm getting `There was an error running the query [Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now]`

error at second query, even tho I've freed the result. And I know the `mysqli_result::free` method works, because when I do something like this

```
$result->free();
$result->free();
```

I'm getting `mysqli_result::free(): Couldn't fetch mysqli_result`

And I know that my procedures returns only one result each.

**So the main question is:
Why I'm getting "Commands out of sync" error?**

Also I had similar problem when I was calling procedure that was returning multiple results. Then I had to use `mysqli::next_result` method one extra time to make further queries working. If someone know the answer for this question also, I'll be grateful.

[Added]
OK, so after brainstorm in comments and few more tests I have some more knowledge. What I've noticed is that stored procedures return one extra result, comparing to the code that is in this procedure. I've checked it by executing query with `mysqli::multi_query`. After last (in my example one) result `mysqli::more_results` returns `true`, but next result is empty. Someone knows why?
[/Added]

Comment: `$result` is your data, for example an array representation of a row.  I think you should call `free` on something else.

Comment: @user29 Should not you use `unset($result);` instead?

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix
I don't know on what should I call it then. In all tutorials I've read it's the same.

Comment: I dont use mysqli - PDO

Comment: @Ormoz I don't think so, but I've tried, and the error is still there.

Comment: What are the two stored procedure definitions?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski here you go http://pastebin.com/m3C8NQ0a

Comment: Ok, so you certainly do have only one result set per procedure.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yup, told ya. Yet I still have this error. I don't know what to do. It's the same like in many tutorials, except there was only one query per example and I have two. Of course I can write a single procedure with multiple results and use mysqli::multi_query, but this case keep me awake at night...

Comment: If you change the order of these, call the second SP _before_ the first, does it fail accordingly after the first statement (`Other_Stored_Procedure()`)?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski nice idea, but now `Other_Stored_Procedure()` is working fine and after that I'm getting `There was an error running the query [Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now]`.

Comment: Weird. I really don't know what to say. I've seen hard to spot problems before, wherein the wrong variable name was used when calling `free()`, but your code looks all correct in that regard.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I've made some more tests and I found the source of the problem. It is in `$sql`. I've changed first `CALL` to corresponding SQL query and then the second `CALL` is working. But why the hell SQL works, and procedure isn't? I don't know.

Comment: @user2984134 Possibly because of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683177/commands-out-of-sync-while-calling-stored-procedure-mysql.  I can't test right now, but it may be that MySQLi gets one result set for output vars from the procedure and the actual SQL results are in the second. I don't remember encountering this myself, but I did vaguely remember seeing here on SO before.

Comment: @user2984134 Also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903481/2nd-call-to-stored-procedure-gives-error-2014

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski so _"SPs return second resultset which contains the status"_ for some reason. That's understandable. Too bad I can't find a tutorial mentioning that. And I can't see a way to grab or display it. `mysqli::next_result` returns `true` and then `$result = $mysqli->store_result()` returns `false`. Anyway if you sum up our conversation, I'll flag it as best answer.

Comment: @MichałCzarnecki I'll link it against the other actually, since I don't know anymore than Peterm already has there. Cheers.